# JSON parsing results in nscfarray inside nsrray obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am converting JSON formatted data from an MQTT message with

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

As a result I got a dictionary and it is as follows

```
{colorCode = "#0000FF";
label = "Tornado Warning";
locations =     (
            {
        account = 3;
        "floor_plan" =             (
            18
        );
        id = 11;
        label = "Albert Elementary School (ES)";
    }
);
msgType = AlertInitiated;
origin = webapp; }
```

For fetching the floor_plan array, using the following code.

```
NSDictionary *locations = [dict valueForKey:@"locations"];
NSArray *floor_plan = [locations valueForKey:@"floor_plan"];
```

I got the `floor_plan` as:

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7fa87b5919f0>(
  <__NSCFArray 0x7fa87b5af8d0>(
    18
  )
)
```

Why NSCFAray is generating inside in NSArray? 
Note :- The same json is parsing in android and the floor_plan array is getting as a normal array.

Comment: locations is not dictionary, its array. try [[dict valueForKey:@"locations"] firstObject]. it should work fine. NSCFAray is cosntant array being generated when you try to access it with key locations.

Comment: Thank pawan. Tried like this and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray <NSDictionary <NSString *,id> *> *locations = json[@"locations"];
NSDictionary <NSString *,id> *firstLocation = locations.firstObject;
NSArray *floorPlan = firstLocation[@"floor_plan"];
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure locations variable dictionary looks ok...

Then try this:

```
NSArray *floor_plan = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[locations valueForKey:@"floor_plan"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried like this and it worked.

`NSArray *floor_plan = [[locations valueForKey:@"floor_plan"] firstObject];`